# Android 12, ClipboardManager.getClassificationStatus always return CLASSIFICATION_NOT_COMPLETE [1]

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

I use

```
ClipboardManager.primaryClipDescription.getConfidenceScore(TextClassifier.TYPE_URL)
```

every call returns java.lang.IllegalStateException: Classification not complete.

**How to get the probability of data from the clipboard?**

Comment: I have no clue what it does, but reading from the docs - Returns a score indicating confidence that an instance of the given entity is present in the first item of the clip data, **if that item is plain text and text classification has been performed** maybe text classification was not performed?

Comment: The problem is that it always fails no matter what the content.

Comment: Well, as I said, I'm not familiar at all with those functions and what they do, but maybe the content you are checking, all of it, was not classified? don't even know what it means